# Why can't Guava's identity function be used in place of a function that transforms a list to an iterable?

Tags: java, guava

For legacy reasons, I have to re-implement some of my Java 8 code using Java 7 and Guava. The original code looks like this:

```
someMethodReturningSetofListofStrings().stream()
                                       .forEach((List<String> ts) -> ts.stream()
                                                                       .forEach(...);
```

With Guava, I am going with the [FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) class, and here is my attempt:

```
Function<List<String>, Iterable<String>> f = new Function<List<String>, Iterable<String>>() {
            public Iterable<String> apply(List<String> list) { return list; }
        }

FluentIterable.from(someMethodReturningSetofListofStrings()).transformAndConcat(f);
```

I thought that defining the function `f` would be unnecessary because it is the identity function, and I could just use [Functions#identity()](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#identity()).

But my IDE (Intellij IDEA 14) complains that `transformAndConcat(List<String>, Iterable<?>) cannot be applied to Function<Object, Object>`. I don't understand why, since a `List` is obviously an `Iterable`.

Comment: Why this function in the first place?

Comment: @fge Not sure I follow. I have a method returning `Set<List<String>>`, and I want it to be transformed to just a `List<String>`. The `FluentIterable#transformAndConcat()` method seems well suited for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is failure of type inference, in which case you can always explicitly supply the types

```
transformAndConcat(Function.<List<String>>identity());
```

In java8, type inference is improved, and the following code compiles in java8

```
transformAndConcat(Function.identity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iterables.concat`:

```
Iterables.concat(someMethodReturningSetofListofStrings())
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing because I didn't like the dummy identity function (`f` in the question here). But my question remains: why wasn't `Functions#identity()` allowed in place of my dummy `f`?